# Find the difference between two collections in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to make a `List` of all of the books in one `Collection` that are not present in another. My problem is that I need to compare based on book ID, so I can't just test to see whether a book in the first is contained in the second, I have to determine whether any book in the second collection has the same ID as a book in the first.

I have the below code to compare two collections of books and filter the first collection:

> ```
> List<Book> parentBooks = listOfBooks1.stream().filter(book->
>   !listOfBooks2.contains(book)).collect(Collectors.toList());
> ```

The code doesn't work correctly because I am comparing the objects themselves. I need to compare the objects based on the bookId instead of the whole book object. How should I change the code so it can do the comparison based on the bookId (book.getId())?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
List<Book> books1 = ...;
List<Book> books2 = ...;
Set<Integer> ids = books2.stream()
        .map(Book::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<Book> parentBooks = books1.stream()
        .filter(book -> !ids.contains(book.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If anyone's wondering why Set (ids), why not List, like me? It's because Set's "contains" operation takes O(1).

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the solution. It works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: books1 = {Book1}, books2 = {}, ids = Book1[{Book1}], parentBooks stream books2 is blank, so no stream. So, parentBook empty

Comment: And, it will satisfy subset if 2nd parameter is subset

Comment: It should be noted that this method does not account for any duplicate entries that might exist in either list. If, for example, a specific book happens to be listed twice in one of the lists, this method will identify the duplicate in the results so it's not technically a method that determines all books in one list that don't exist in the other. I was only able to determine whether or not there really was a difference by utilizing a Map with its putIfAbsent method which let me iterate through both lists and build maps that truly contain only one of each item in each list.

Comment: @MichaelSims add `Stream.distinct` step and you'll get list without duplicates

Answer (score 4):

The problem is complex, but it boils down to one thing, knows your data. Is it immutables, entities with an id, duplicate entries etc?

The code below works for immutables with only values (and with possible duplicates).

It first tries to remove all entries in the before list (from the copied after-list).

What is left will be the added elements. The ones from the before-list that can be removed from the after-list are the unchanged ones.

The rest are the removed ones

```
public class ListDiffer<T> {

    private List<T> addedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<T> unchangedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<T> removedList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListDiffer(List<T> beforeList, List<T> afterList) {
        addedList.addAll(afterList); // Will contain only new elements when all elements in the Before-list are removed.
        beforeList.forEach(e -> {
            boolean b = addedList.remove(e) ? unchangedList.add(e) : removedList.add(e);
        });
    }

    public List<T> getAddedList() {
        return addedList;
    }

    public List<T> getUnchangedList() {
        return unchangedList;
    }

    public List<T> getRemovedList() {
        return removedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: can you please edit that description into the answer?